# Correct way to reference sub bullet list

Tags: writing-style, lists, citation, tech-writing

```
d. Include documentation of rating ______

    i. Show rating of ______
    ii. Include overall ______

        1. Provide relevant documentation ______
```

In the example above, how would the last 3 lines be correctly cited back?

The only way I could think of would be  (dI, dII, d1)

Would that be incorrect?

Comment: Folks, if the question is not clear to you, you *can* ask.

Comment: Which style are you required to follow?

Comment: I would naturally it should be **(dI, dII, dII1)** instead, but may depend.

Comment: I'm not sure, it's for business/administrative, if that helps.